# can dynamic paint work only at weighted vertex?

Tags: vertex-weights

[image]

Can I use dynamic paint to only weighted vertices?

desired effect is the picture below.  i made left picture by using shrink wrap modifire with baked mesh, but i hope if there are way to do it more simple.
[image]

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly that you want the particles to deform/displace only those parts of the sphere where it's weighted, i.e. the red part should be affected by the particles but not the blue part?

Comment: thank you for comment.   yes, like shrinkwrap can change shape only on choosed vertex group.

Comment: What is your desired final effect? You may be able to use a _Vertex Weight Mix_ modifier to restrict the influence of your DP, as opposed to the DP itself?

Comment: Thank you for a comment robin, I could make restricted weight paint by vertex weight mix, and I can use "displace modifire" or "wave modifire" using that restricted vertex group to look same with dynamic paint's "wave".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the surface type which you choose:

[image]

"Paint" changes only vertex colors.

"Weight" changes the weight of vertex groups.

Comment: thank you very much "weight" and "paint" are conplicated. "weight" can change the only choosed vertex group? or it change whole part of hit point?